# Trying to work with Polymer paper-toggle-button

Tags: javascript, polymer, material-design

Sorry if this is a dumb question but I'm trying to figure out how to use `paper-toggle-button` to make an element appear/disappear on my page.

I can make it work by simply using `onclick` but this is obviously not right/ideal and I can't find any examples online of it being used (for web).

The toggle button is deployed (without the `onclick='toggleShow'()`) as:

```
<paper-toggle-button onchange={{toggleShow}} checked></paper-toggle-button>
```

The script I've tried (and failed with) is:

```
function toggleShow() {
  if (checked: false) {
    chart.hide('upload'); //this works with onclick
  } else {
    chart.show('upload');
  }
}
```

I'm sure this is a bit of a dumb question, but any help to get me going in the right direction would be really appreciated

Comment: `if (checked: false){` is a syntax error (unless polymer is doing syntax transforms)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var toggle = document.querySelector("paper-toggle-button");
toggle.addEventListener('change', function () {
  if (this.checked) {
    // do something if when checked
  } else {
    // do something if not checked
  }
});
```

the above code will check for the "change" event that is fired when the toggle gets user interaction and will check the state of the button.

if you were going to use this in a custom element you could wrap it in the ready function. you would give the toggle a id (in this case i used toggle) so you can select it with polymers quick select.

```
ready: function () {
  this.$.toggle.addEventListener('change', function () {
    if (this.checked) {
      // do something if when checked
    } else {
      // do something if not checked
    }
  }); 
}
```

edit: didn't notice on first posting that op used onchange attribute so you can ignore the part about the event listener and just use the named function as OP posted. just need to correct the logic.

second edit: here is a plunker with examples of both methods on-change attribute and also eventlistener. http://plnkr.co/edit/3tn3C2GpgKQY9bkzCt0L?p=preview

op used onchange in place on on-change which might have been a root of the issue to begin with.

Comment: This was great (small typo) on toggle.addEventListener (capital L), but otherwise did exactly what I was looking for.

Another question - querySelector simply grabs the first element. Would I be able to use querySelectorAll to get all the paper-toggle-button on the page?

Comment: sorry about the L's worse the making the mistake it looks like i did it 2 times. damn my being human. yes you can collect groups of elements with querySelectorAll. then parse though the object like normal. i did have issue setting attributes with the element.attribute = value i had to use element.setAttribute(attribute, value);

Comment: No worries - the answer was great, just wanted to make sure others knew in case they stumbled across it

Answer (score 4):

I think property binding is a more idiomatic way to approach it, something like this:

```
<paper-toggle-button checked="{{showChart}}"></paper-toggle-button>

<div id="chart" hidden$="[[!showChart]]">...</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This one should work:

```
<paper-toggle-button on-change="toggleShow" checked></paper-toggle-button>
```